# Azure Elastic Scale Sharding Key

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-elastic-scale

I am moving my datamodel to Azure Elastic Scale.

After some testing and some experiences I fall in love if it, it is simple and with that kind of approach the code remains clean and easy to maintain.

I just have one big question, **where is the Sharding key defined**? I cannot find info on the sample downloaded from Visual Studio and I can beat that this is a straight forward answer.

In the sample offered by Microsoft the default sharding key is *CustomerId* but i cannot find where the reference to that key takes place.

Could it be in ShardMapName from configuration file?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no explicit link between the the sharding key in the SQL schema and its usage (in code).

So in the Getting Started sample, the Customers and Orders table both contain a `CustomerId` column, and you can see that in DataDependentRoutingSample.cs when we access these tables we make sure to provide the same `customerId` value to the `shardMap.OpenConnectionForKey` method that we then use for customerId column (both in the SELECT and INSERT statements) in the following query.

```
// Looks up the key in the shard map and opens a connection to the shard
using (SqlConnection conn = shardMap.OpenConnectionForKey(customerId, credentialsConnectionString))
{
    // Create a simple command that will insert or update the customer information
    SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = @"
    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Customers WHERE CustomerId = @customerId)
        UPDATE Customers
            SET Name = @name, RegionId = @regionId
            WHERE CustomerId = @customerId
    ELSE
        INSERT INTO Customers (CustomerId, Name, RegionId)
        VALUES (@customerId, @name, @regionId)";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@customerId", customerId);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", name);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@regionId", regionId);
    cmd.CommandTimeout = 60;

    // Execute the command
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

In other words, when you provide a certain key value in the `OpenConnectionForKey` call, it's your responsibility to make sure that all SQL queries with that connection are restricted to that key value, otherwise you may end up with incorrect results (e.g. if it was a SELECT query) or rows living on the wrong shard (e.g. if it was an INSERT query).

It's possible to fix this safety issue by using the new Row-Level Security feature. We have a sample called [Entity Framework Multi-Tenant Shards](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/vstudio/Elastic-DB-Tools-for-Azure-aea52c05) that demonstrates how to combine Shard Maps with Row-Level Security. The relevant code is in [ElasticScaleContext.cs](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/vstudio/Elastic-DB-Tools-for-Azure-aea52c05/sourcecode?fileId=136900&pathId=713842411):

```
SqlConnection conn = null; 
try 
{ 
    // Ask shard map to broker a validated connection for the given key 
    conn = shardMap.OpenConnectionForKey(shardingKey, connectionStr, ConnectionOptions.Validate); 

    // Set CONTEXT_INFO to shardingKey to enable Row-Level Security filtering 
    SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand(); 
    cmd.CommandText = @"SET CONTEXT_INFO @shardingKey"; 
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@shardingKey", shardingKey); 
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 

    return conn; 
} 
catch (Exception) 
{ 
    if (conn != null) 
    { 
        conn.Dispose(); 
    } 

    throw; 
}
```

Thanks for your great question!

Comment: That's a great answer thanks. My app uses entity framework but I don't really want to be dependent on that so I can move to another framework anytime I want. Anyway that as a great help and I think this question will help a lot o people in the future

Comment: Cheers. I'd like to clarify that the above snippet that uses `@"SET CONTEXT_INFO @shardingKey"` is independent of EF and you could easily use the same technique with raw SqlClient, Dapper, or whatever other SQL Server database access layer you prefer.